# Invoke method in another class's try catch block

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have some methods that follow this pattern

```
try(Connection connection = MySqlConnection.getConnection()){
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(
                "Insert into db values (NULL ,?,?,?,?,?, NULL , ?)",
                Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        ...
        statement.executeUpdate();
        ...
    }
    catch(SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

I was told to extract try-catch with connection to class MySqlConnection and create a new method that would execute all logic and encapsulate creating connection. So, I don't quite get this approach and have no idea, how to resolve it without writing some ugly templates or strategies. Would it be better to just leave it as it is, or can it be implemented in an easy way?

Comment: "I was told" ask the person who told you.

Comment: The code provided in your question looks like it meets the specifications already, or are you not sure how to implement `MySqlConnection.getConnection()`?

Comment: @AndyTurner I expected this question =). The weird thing is that I can't contact this person right now, but work has to be done.

Comment: @Anguium this sort of thing can be refactored easily using something like structural search and replace in intellij. Write all of the methods consistently, and then refactor them all in one go once the person who knows how they want it done returns. Anything we suggest is probably not what they intended, so you'd have to redo it anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a **ConnectionHelper** that will deal with exceptions. This is a little bit tricky, you have to define your own functional interface because standard Consumer does not work with checked SQLExceptions:

```
public class ConnectionHelper {

    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface ConnectionConsumer {
        void accept(Connection connection) throws SQLException;
    }

    public static void doWithConnection(ConnectionConsumer connectionConsumer) {
        try (Connection connection = MySqlConnection.getConnection()) {
            connectionConsumer.accept(connection);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
public void doSomeUpdate() {
    ConnectionHelper.doWithConnection(connection -> {
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(
                "Insert into db values (NULL ,?,?,?,?,?, NULL , ?)",
                Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        statement.executeUpdate();
    });
}
```

This works well as long as you don't have to return anything from your database, which is rarely the case. So we need to extend the helper with another functional interface, `ConnectionFunction`, to be used when an object needs to be returned:

```
public class ConnectionHelper {

    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface ConnectionConsumer {
        void accept(Connection connection) throws SQLException;
    }

    public static void doWithConnection(ConnectionConsumer connectionConsumer) {
    ...
    }

    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface ConnectionFunction<T> {
        T apply(Connection connection) throws SQLException;
    }

    public static <T> T doWithConnection(ConnectionFunction<T> connectionFunction) {
        try (Connection connection = MySqlConnection.getConnection()) {
            return connectionFunction.apply(connection);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
public boolean doSomeQuery() {
    return ConnectionHelper.doWithConnection(connection -> {
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM table");
        return statement.execute();
    });
}
```

**Updates**
2 solutions to work with `SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException`:

**Own, runtime exception**:
As this is a runtime exception, you just add try-catch where needed.

```
public static class MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException extends RuntimeException {
    public MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException(Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
    }
}

public static void doWithConnection(ConnectionConsumer connectionConsumer)       {
    try (Connection connection = MySqlConnection.getConnection()) {
        connectionConsumer.accept(connection);
    } catch (SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException e) {
        throw new MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException(e);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

**insertWithConnection**:
A specialized version of `doWithConnection()`. Again, use it only where/when applicable.

```
public static void insertWithConnection(ConnectionConsumer connectionConsumer) throws SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException {
    try (Connection connection = MySqlConnection.getConnection()) {
        connectionConsumer.accept(connection);
    } catch (SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException e) {
        throw e;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks like a better version of what I tried to do, but it still has some problems. When it's used to insert data, it can throw SQLIntegrityConstraintVIolationException for duplicate entries. To simply rethrow it, I have to add this to doWithConnection signature. This is where things get complicated. Because of this signature I have to catch aforementioned exception where it can't possibly be thrown, like, when I "Select" data. Doesn't make any sense, right?

Comment: @Anguium there are 2 solutions for that: either you create your own, runtime, IntegrityViolationException. Or you create an `insertWithConnection()` in the helper. See my updates.

Answer (score 1):

Use java functional interface to separate exception handling from business logic, like this:

```
public class ExceptionHandler() {

    public R execute(Function<T,R> function, T argument) {
        try {
           return function.apply(argument)
        } catch (Exception e) {
           throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can pass to the class above any function that will contain your logic and handling exception will be independent.

Furthermore, this way you can create many useful methods, and classes that work like a proxy, or which are needed for every operation, and hat will be independent of your business logic.

For example, in the same way, you can write:

1. your own transaction management,
2. logging input and output
3. check user and permissions
4. and any other interceptor