# Service and controller layer exception handling design pattern

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, controller, layer

So here is my current implementation of a rest-api endpoint, I would like to handle some kind of corner cases, for example the user or the flat is not found, so I would throw and suitable exception, but how show I handle it in the controller? For now it's not really working, if I set a not exists id it'll work as usual, and I don't get the correspondig error message.

Service layer:

```
public void delete(Long flatId) {
        flatRepository.findById(flatId).ifPresentOrElse(flat -> {
                    List<User> residents = flat.getResidents();
                    residents.forEach(resident -> resident.setFlat(null));
                    flatRepository.delete(flat);
                },
                () -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Flat " + flatId + " found"));

}
```

Controller Layer:

```
@DeleteMapping("/flats/{flatId}")
    public void deleteFlat(@PathVariable Long flatId) {
        flatService.delete(flatId);
}
```

GlobalExceptionHandler:

```
@ControllerAdvice
@RestController
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public final ErrorDetails handleResourceNotFoundException(ResourceNotFoundException ex) {
        return new ErrorDetails(LocalDateTime.now(), ex.getMessage(), 404);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(ResourceAlreadyDefinedException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CONFLICT)
    public final ErrorDetails handleResourceAlreadyDefinedException(ResourceAlreadyDefinedException ex) {
        return new ErrorDetails(LocalDateTime.now(),  ex.getMessage(), 409);
    }

}
```

Update: I created this global exception handler, but if I send a delete request towards my api with a not exists id, it wont't send me a 404 it will just reply 200. While If I have a return value like in this case, it works as expected.

```
        public Flat get(Long id) {
                return flatRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Flat " + id + " not found"));
        }


     @GetMapping("/flats/{flatId}")
        public ResponseEntity<Flat> getFlat(@PathVariable Long flatId) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(flatService.get(flatId));
     }
```

Comment: I have an answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53762829/can-a-method-annotation-handle-errors-thrown-by-this-method/53770233#53770233     hope it helps

Comment: @Cocuthemyth updated my post!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `@ControllerAdvice` with `@ExceptionHandler` to implement global exception handling for all controllers and for specific type of exception.

Look [here](https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring) for examples.